# Why doesn't the int-based access work for std::get(std::tuple)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 underlines "std::get" red, therefore the program doesn't compile. What can I do to make it work?

A snippet:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int>t;
t = {1,1,1};
int a = 0;
int b = std::get<a>(t);
```

Comment: Generally, when program doesn't compile, the compiler gives you a diagnostic message. Did you not get any message?

Comment: "Visual Studio 2017 underlines "std::get" red, therefore " the causality is a bit different. VS underlining the code is just a convenience feature of the IDE. To really be sure if it compiles or why not you have to compile it and read the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template arguments are evaluated at compile time. You can fix your error by using `constexpr` to make it possible for the compiler to evaluate the value of `a` at compile time.

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> t;
t = {1, 1, 1};
constexpr int a = 0;
int b = std::get<a>(t);
```

Alternatively, if your tuple contains only one type of element, you can replace it with a `std::array` or `std::vector` (or any similar container) and perform the subscript at run time.

```
std::array<int, 3> array;
t = {1, 1, 1};
int a = 0;
int b = array[a];
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to use a variable without knowing its value at compile time?

Comment: @JiW No, not if you want to use it as part of a template argument. Templates are instantiated at compile time. It's an inherent part of their design.

Comment: @JiW There are some tricks to make it work, but only if the `tuple` consists of elements of the same type. And if it does, you might as well use `std::array` instead.

Comment: @JiW Since `tuple` elements can have different types, the compiler needs to know which element you are getting since it needs to know the type.

Answer (score 2):

`get` is a template so `a` has to be known at compile time and so it should be a `constexpr`.

```
constexpr int a = 0;
```